# Obtener img con axios que me retorna una url

Tags: vue.js, axios, javascript-objeto

```
const vm = new Vue({
created(){
    axios.get(this.https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon)
    .then(res => console.log(res.data.results)) 
},
```

**Estoy tratando de obtener una imagen de esta petición, pero la imagen está dentro de otra url que obtengo como respuesta y quiero saber como acceder a ella, debo hacer otra petición?**

Comment: ¿Como deseas usar la imagen, la colocaras en un `<img src" ">`? no entendí bien lo de "la imagen esta en otra URL"

Comment: Correcto, estoy esperando varias propiedades que voy a usar en un template pero la única que me llega directa desde la petición es el name, pero las otras me llegan en una url.

Comment: Sí, me parece que esa es la solución. Muchas gracias.